# SVG Path having weird rounded-corner blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I'm new to SVG so this is probably not very weird but can anyone help me solve a problem with Highcharts and SVG here.

I used a jsfiddle which I found on the web and trying to customize it to my use.
Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/qs7FY/

The issue I'm facing is the rounded corner blocks of line seen in the Result panel.

Can someone help me resolve this ?

Thanks in advance!

See the problem in the screenshot below

See the problem here[image]

Comment: one up for the jsfiddle ... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADD this to the end of your code

```
   $('svg path ').each(function(index,value) {
    var myd = $(this).attr('d') ; 
    var indexofc = myd.indexOf('C') ; 
    var indexofL = myd.indexOf('L') - 1 ; 
    if(indexofc != -1){
     var final = myd.slice(indexofc ,indexofL) ;
    }
    var end = myd.replace(final ,'') ; 
    $(this).attr('d',end) ;

   });
```

your chart after fixing [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/qs7FY/9/)

*Update*

what makes your lines curving is that the add `C = curveto` to your lines so if i remove the they will be straight as you can see after updating your jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/qs7FY/9/

and here is how one of your path looks like with `C`

```
  <path fill="none" d="M 102.29523731301347 84.2399490981872 
   C 107.29523731301347 
   84.2399490981872 113.95649598906613 88.67025753561153 123.11572666863853 
    94.76193163706998 L 132.27495734821093 100.85360573852843"
   stroke-width="1" 
   stroke="#004c67" visibility="visible" zIndex="3" transform="translate(10,40)">
       </path>
```

so i loop through your `d` element taking out every thing betweebn `C` and `L` and ending up having something like the following :

```
       <path fill="none" d="M 102.29523731301347 84.2399490981872 
   L 132.27495734821093 100.85360573852843"
   stroke-width="1" 
   stroke="#004c67" visibility="visible" zIndex="3" transform="translate(10,40)">
       </path>
```

and this should take of the curves ... please consider seeing the jsFiddle

Comment: could you please explain what you just did ? Thanks!

Comment: ..and...I still see those blocks of rounded-cap lines at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed on the svg-developers mailinglist, for some solutions see [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/65666).

The rounded-cap lines is just a pattern tile problem. You might realize what you're doing wrong by drawing the pattern tile yourself and then try to tile it (cutting away everything that overflows the pattern tile). For an illustration you can try searching for "seamless tiles".